# Use variables in find command

Tags: linux, shell

`mount |awk '{print $3}'` --> list of mount points

```
find "list of mount points"  -name  "aaa" -print
```

How can I redirect the result from previous line into find command as searching directory?

I would like to have it done in one line:

```
mount |awk '{print $3}' | find "converting pipe result to a variable as directory" -name "aaa" -print
```

Possible to make it work this way?

Comment: This is probably not what you want on `linux`, since you will be using find on psuedo-filesystems such as `proc` and `sysfs`.

Answer (score 3):

> Possible to make it work this way?

Yes, with `xargs`:

```
mount |awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I {} find {} -name "aaa" -print
```

You can even make it search your hard drives in parallel, if you add `-P n` after `xargs` for maximum `n` simultaneous processes (this is a GNU extension).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution): substitute the output of a command into a command line.

```
find $(mount |awk '{print $3}') -name "aaa" -print
```

This only works if the mount points don't contain any whitespace or `*?\[`. This restriction is rarely a problem for mount points (but do make sure that you don't have mount points with space characters — the `awk` command would not parse them correctly anyway).

You need to tell `find` not to traverse mount points, otherwise `find /` already traverses your whole system. Pass the `-xdev` option.

```
find $(mount |awk '{print $3}') -xdev -name "aaa" -print
```

Note that you should probably not run `find` on all the mounted filesystems, as there are filesystems for internal system use that can be quite large and contain a lot of files that you don't have permission to read (causing spurious error messages). Instead of getting the list of filesystems from `mount`, get it from `df`, which omits some of these filesystems.

```
find $(df -P |awk 'NR != 1 {print $6}') -xdev -name "aaa" -print
```